# Question about Authentication on MONGODB+Node

Tags: node.js

I have a tutorial how to create it, 
im on stage he tell me to do something like this "user-registration $export PrivateKey=SecureAF"
what is this mean? what should i do ?

The ERROR at "npm start" is : "FATAL ERROR: PrivateKey is not defined."

index.js :

```
const config = require('config');
const Joi = require('joi');
Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

if (!config.get('PrivateKey')) {
    console.error('FATAL ERROR: PrivateKey is not defined.');
    process.exit(1);
}

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0-7n3bu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('Now connected to MongoDB!'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Something went wrong', err));

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/auth', auth);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: Hi there! Please can you share the value of `start` script from your package.json?

Comment: `{
  "name": "a2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/hoek": "^9.0.4",
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "@hapi/topo": "^5.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "joi-objectid": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.5"
  }
}
` @Tunmee

Comment: Thanks. The`start` script is executing your index.js so please can you also share the content of index.js. I would suggest you add that to the question, it would be difficult to read in the comment section.

Comment: @Tunmee added man

Comment: Hmm... now we can see where the error is coming from. `PrivateKey` is not present in your config. I'm guessing you have a config folder in the root of your application, yes? If yes, can you check your `./config/default.json` or `./config/development.json` to confirm that there is a `PrivateKey` config property with a valid value?

Comment: @Tunmee i put  `{
  "PrivateKey": "SecureAF"
}` on default.json in config folder , now no errors !!! thanks you m8, do you know how to built form login and password for client will work with mongo and node?

Comment: Yes, I do. However, I think that discussion is going outside the scope of this question, perhaps we can move it to a different thread. Also, I would submit the comment above as an answer so that others can easily benefit from the fix and I can also get some rep :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why you are having the error:**

The check below in `index.js` is what leads to the error:

```
if (!config.get('PrivateKey')) {
    console.error('FATAL ERROR: PrivateKey is not defined.');
    process.exit(1);
}
```

`config.get('PrivateKey')` is supposed to get the value of `PrivateKey` in your config, however, it seems that value is not present, consequently, the app exits with the error log.

**The fix:**
I'm guessing you have a config folder in the root of your application, yes? If yes, check your `./config/default.json` or `./config/development.json` and confirm that there is a `PrivateKey` config property with a valid value.